# Possible to have a simple formula within the [value_if] argument? - excel

Tags: syntax, excel-formula

I'm trying to use a relatively basic IF function but having no luck - i'm sure i just have brackets or parenthesis wrong or something. Reckon it will be childsplay for you guys....

The formula is intended to show how many days a date has passed by. Date is shown in T column.

Basically it was working fine as the following, both for pending and past dates:
=IF(T7<=TODAY(), (TODAY()-T7),-(T7-TODAY()))

But I got greedy and wanted it to return more of a statement when the date has passed, as to how much it has passed by. So I've tried to make this happen with:

=IF(T7<=TODAY(),"EffOut(TODAY()-T7) days ago",-(T7-TODAY()))

Hoping it would enter "EffOut 8 days ago" (when TODAY()-T7 is 8 days) for example. 
But it doesnt - it shows the entire argument i.e "EffOut(TODAY()-T7) days ago" in the return cell.

Is it possible to have a kind of embedded formula in the 'value_if' fields, mixed with text in this sense?

Happy to share the document if that would help, but will need to clear the data first so just let me know.

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated! Having read other posts I think it will just be a simple fix but its well beyond me! (I only got this far by perusing forums...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this...

```
=IF(T7<=TODAY(),"EffOut "&DAYS(TODAY(),T7)&" days ago",-(T7-TODAY()))
```

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(T7<=TODAY(),"EffOut "&(TODAY()-T7)&" days ago",-(T7-TODAY()))`

You just need to be careful to put "" around any strings. This is how Excel knows that's not a part of the formula. Remember to out the spaces is to the string like I did above so it looks like a sentence. The & sign combines the results of the calculated parts and the strings.